# Objective C AES256 Decryption

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have to decrypt (AES 256) a String in objective c.

I have the Key and the IV used by the other side to encrypt (C#).

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have look at this [application](https://github.com/mayurbirari/AES256AndBase64).

All you need to do is to add Helper classes from repository [AES256AndBase64](https://github.com/mayurbirari/AES256AndBase64) in your application,
`#import "NSString+AESCrypt.h"` in your required file.

Use `- (NSString *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key` method to decrypt the data:

```
    NSString* dummyString=@"Steve Job";

    NSLog(@"Normal String- %@",dummyString);

    NSString* encrypt_decrypt_Key=@"apple";

    NSString *encryptString = [dummyString
                                  AES256EncryptWithKey:encrypt_decrypt_Key];

    NSLog(@"Encrypt String- %@",encryptString);

    NSString *decryptString = [encryptString
                               AES256DecryptWithKey:encrypt_decrypt_Key];

    NSLog(@"Decrypt String- %@",decryptString);
```

Comment: how can I use IV value here?