# Encrypt decrypt sign data (unsigned char array) objective c

Tags: objective-c, security, encryption, sign

I've unsigned char array data in objective-c .

I need the following:

1- Encrypt, decrypt this data with "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding",

2- Encrypt, decrypt this data with "AES256bit" with byte array key only (not IV),

3- Sign data with "SHA256withRSA".

**Note:**

- I've certificate with public, and private key to sign.
- I read some reference but I can't reach to the right one with example.

([RSA implementations in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222524/rsa-implementations-in-objective-c), [Objective C AES256 Decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515250/objective-c-aes256-decryption), [AES256 NSString Encryption in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287727/aes256-nsstring-encryption-in-ios),)

- If you boost your reference with example, I'll be grateful to you.

  Thank you in advance

**Modification:**

I need example to encrypt, decrypt data with "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", where the certificate (or public and private keys ) are **Base64**.

Comment: post your code which you tried and let us know where you have problem in understading.

Comment: @M.Yasser Is it that you want to combine all of that into a single operation? You certainly can do hybrid encryption along with signing the ciphertext or something like that. Have you tried that? What are your results?

Comment: @ArtjomB. no, I need separated operation for every one,
In general I found out the AES256, 
So, I need the fisrt and third point  "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", and sign data,
Thank you for your interest